# Issue with ObservableStack<T> implementation and XAML Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, uwp

Where have I gone wrong with my implementation of a `ObservableStack<T>`? The XAML is failing to bind to it some how and so the information contained in the stack is not showing in the UI. If I only change the type of the property in the ViewModel from my `ObservableStack<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>` then the UI elements appear. This makes me think it's the implementation.

I want to use this so my elements appear in the UI in Stack order and not collection order.

Here is my implementation:

```
public class ObservableStack<T> :  INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, ICollection , IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable , IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    ObservableCollection<T> _coll = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    public ObservableStack()
    {
        _coll.CollectionChanged += _coll_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableStack(IEnumerable<T> items) : base()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Push(item);
        }
    }

    private void _coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        _coll.Insert(0, item);
    }

    public void Pop()
    {
        _coll.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    public T Peek
    {
        get { return _coll[0]; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ICollection)_coll).Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ICollection)_coll).IsSynchronized;
        }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ICollection)_coll).SyncRoot;
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((ICollection)_coll).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection)_coll).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)_coll).GetEnumerator();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: "The XAML is failing to bind to it some how" OK, maybe you could, you know, show us the XAML that's failing? And how the DataContext is assigned? And the viewmodel? You know, minimal, complete, verifiable, etc.? You're telling us precisely nothing about the binding itself, or its (intended) source or target. But you want us to tell you what's wrong with it. Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Well, technically this ObservableStack would work for WPF and UWP if placed in a portable assembly that targets the appropriate frameworks.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, I agree with ibebbs. I see no reason why SO members from both areas couldn't comment and benefit from responses.

Comment: Fair enough. Consider adding the PCL tag then -- often people confuse UWP with WPF which can lead to different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is that I needed to implement IList on my ObservableStack. After that everything worked as expected. Curiously, just implementing `IList<T>` didn't work. It needed the non generic interface. Thanks again to those who offered help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to attach the internal `CollectionChanged` handler in the second constructor.

So call the other constructor (instead of the base class constructor) like this:

```
public ObservableStack(IEnumerable<T> items)
   : this() // instead of base()
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Push(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I spotted this too. Corrected it, but it makes no difference. In response to Ed Plunket, I try to post an edit to give more information.

Comment: You should at least also register a handler for the ObservableCollection's PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Hi @Clemens , thanks for the reply. The PropertyChanged event isn't available to subscribe to.

Comment: Hi @Clemens looking at the docs I see ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged despite me trying to directly subscribe to the event so maybe a cast is in order!